# Question about zero sets and measure theory

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $Z\subset\mathbb{R}$ is a zero set we know that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable covering of $Z$ by open intervals $(a_i,b_i)$ such that:
$$\sum_i^\infty b_i-a_i<\epsilon$$
This definition was pretty much ripped straight from Pugh. Now in an excerise in Pugh I'm supposed to show that the statement:

$Z$ is the zero zero set

Is equivalent to:

For each $\epsilon>0$ there is a countable covering of $Z$ by closed intervals $[a_i, b_i]$ with total length $\sum b_i - a_i < \epsilon$.

Now whats throwing me through a loop here is the use of closed intervals. I know that $Z$ can be covered by open intervals, but does that somehow allow me to also cover it with closed intervals? Am I missing something completely obvious?

Comment: Hint: $(a_i,b_i)\subset [a_i,b_i]$ for all $i$

Comment: Hint for the other direction: $[a_i,b_i] \subset (a_i - \epsilon/2^i, b_i + \epsilon/2^i)$.

Comment: Is there something missing in your first sentence? As it stands it reads like the claim that every subset $Z$ of $\mathbb{R}$ has measure zero. This sounds intuitively very wrong

Comment: @Vincent From the title I assume that $Z$ is a zero set. Would be good if OP would mention this in the question itself.

Comment: This is badly written. What is $Z?$ The series you wrote, which needs parentheses, is a sum of negative terms. Take a little time and present your question clearly.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I'll update the post accordingly. Yes we are assuming $Z$ is a zero set.

Comment: A zero set of what?

Comment: @zhw Idk, Pugh calls sets that have this property zero set, they have "outer measure zero"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have an open cover of $Z$ by intervals $(a_i,b_i)$. Then the closed intervals $[a_i,b_i]$ also cover $Z$ since $(a_i,b_i)\subseteq[a_i,b_i]$ for each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, and the length of each closed interval is the same as the length of the corresponding open interval, so:
$$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ell\big([a_i,b_i]\big)=\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ell\big((a_i,b_i)\big)<\varepsilon.$$
Conversely, suppose you have a cover of $Z$ by closed intervals $[a_i,b_i]$ such that the sum of the lengths $\sum_{i=1}^\infty\ell\big([a_i,b_i]\big)<\varepsilon/2$. For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$, consider the open interval $(a_i',b_i')\equiv(a_i-\varepsilon/2^i,b_i+\varepsilon/2^i)$. Then $[a_i,b_i]\subseteq(a_i',b_i')$ for each $i$, and so the intervals $(a_i',b_i')$ cover $Z$, and the sum of the lengths of these intervals is less than $\varepsilon$. Hence, covering by closed sets is equivalent to covering by open sets.